# JAVA - Check if value is not in other index 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Im stuck on this part of a school project where I have to get the shortest route between two co-ordinates (Traveling Salesman Problem). I made a litle something here to get the co-ords of the nearest neighbour, but a few co-ords have the same closest neighbour, and I dont want that.

I thought of something to clear that issue, but it isn't working, and I can't figure out why.

`distance` is the current distance between the current position and every other. `shortestDistance` kind of speaks for itself I think.

`locations[20][3]` is a 2D array in which I store the Xco-ord, the Yco-ord and the nearest neighbour for each co-ord. X is in [x][0], Y in [x][1] and neighbour in [x][2]

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            int shortestDistance = 100;
            int distance;
            //Looking for nearest neighbour 20 times 
            for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
                //Looking for the closest neighbour here
                distanceX = locations[i][0] - locations[j][0];
                distanceY = locations[i][1] - locations[j][1];
                //To prevent a negative distance:
                if(distanceX < 0){
                    distanceX = distanceX * -1; 
                }
                if(distanceY < 0){
                    distanceY = distanceY * -1;
                }
                //Add distance
                distance = distanceX + distanceY;
                //If current distance is shorter then the shortestdistance, to prevent it does'nt see itself as 'neighbour' and to prevent another co-ord has the same neighbour, which happens in isOk(); 
                if(distance < shortestDistance && distanceX + distanceY != 0 && isOk(j)){
                    shortestDistance = distance;
                    locations[i][2] = j;
                }
            }
        }
```

Function isOk is:

```
private boolean isOk(int j){
    boolean result = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        if(locations[i][2] == j){
            result = false;
        }
        else{
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So, I what I'm asking is what I am doing wrong? I still get some items(in 20 * 10 storage) that have the same item as its nearest neighbour.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: How to prevent indexes, or positions, have the same closest neighbour. Or actually what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Sorry to ask back, but why do you want that?

Comment: So I can make a kind of path. I need to pick 20 items so when I picked  one which has multiple other items as its closest neighbour the path will be broken. I hope you understand it, it's hard to explain for me

Comment: how (or to what value) did you initialize the neighbours in the locations matrix?

Comment: I gave used the index of the closest neighbours. So if the closest item to item 3 was item 5, I put 5 in locations[3][2]. If this is what you mean?

Comment: If I understood correctly that is what you are trying to achieve. Just wondered to what value you initially set the locations arrays. since in `isOk` you check `locations[i][2] == j` for `i` that might not have a neighbour assigned yet. If you just do `new int[3]` then initially all location have 0 as nearest neighbour. On the other hand isOK's for loop is probably not correct. As it is it only simply checks if `location[19][2] == j`. You probably forgot to interrupt the loop when j is found. You might also want to skip i == j.

Comment: Initially all locations have 0 as nearest neighbour yes. Should this be changed to something else? Also thanks for noticing the for loop in isOk, I see it now!

Comment: Yes, i think you should initialize them all to something like -1 so that you will be able to set 0 as a best neighbour for someone.

Comment: Thanks David! The problem was I didn't stop the foor loop in isOk. Setting the nearest neighbour initially to -1 was also something I didn't think about.
By the way, do I have to close this question or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to initialize the neighbors to something that will be ok for your `isOK` method. A such value is, for instance, -1.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) locations[i][2] = -1;
```

The `isOk` contains also a small mistake. The loop should be stopped when `j` has been found as neighbor of another location:

```
private boolean isOk(int j){
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        if (locations[i][2] == j) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I did this and it's fixed, thanks! Do I have to do something with this question now it's awnsered or can I just leave it?

Comment: I think you can just leave it. However, I never asked a question on stackoverflow. :-)